# WPF shows behind currently focussed window after closing splashscreen

Tags: c#, wpf, splash-screen

We have a WPF app which shows a splashscreen during startup

```
    _splashViewModel = new SplashViewModel(versionTrimmed);
    var t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var splash = ShowSplashScreen(_splashViewModel);
        splash.ShowDialog();
    });
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start();
```

When the actual app is created and all its configuration is loaded, we close the splashscreen, and show the main window.

```
    public void StartSystemControl(
        ICardMasterOneViewModel mainViewModel, 
        SplashViewModel splashViewModel,
        Thread thread)
    {
        var mainWindow = new CMOMainWindow { DataContext = mainViewModel };
        System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow = mainWindow;
        splashViewModel.DialogResult = true;
    
        thread.Join();
        mainWindow.Show();
        mainWindow.Activate();
    }
```

The main app will always appear behind the currently focused window, which is annoying.

Attempt 1:

Fix it by setting `mainWindow.TopMost = true` before `mainWindow.Show()`

```
    mainWindow.Topmost = true;
    mainWindow.Show();
    mainWindow.Topmost = false;
```

This solves the problem, but now the WPF app is always on top, even after setting `mainWindow.Topmost = false;` after showing the window. That's unacceptable in our case.

Attempt 2:

Activating the window after showing it

```
    mainWindow.Show();
    mainWindow.Activate();
```

This doesn't change the behavior. I haven't checked but I also would expect the `Show` implicitly activates the window anyway. But anyway, this doesn't solve the problem.

When I comment out the splash screen all together, then the main app shows correctly as expected, on the foreground. Still I can't quite piece together what happens in deeper down in windows with message pumps.

Does anybody have experience with this way of showing splash screens and have a solution for this particular problem?

#### For somebody interested in reproducing this

The splash screen view model

```
    public class SplashViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private bool? dialogResult;
        private string machineFamily;

        public string MachineFamily
        {
            get => machineFamily;
            set { Set(() => MachineFamily, ref machineFamily, value); }
        }

        public string VersionInfo { get; }

        public bool? DialogResult
        {
            get => dialogResult;
            set { Set(() => DialogResult, ref dialogResult, value); }
        }

        public SplashViewModel(string versionInfo)
        {
            VersionInfo = versionInfo;
        }
    }
```

The WPF window

```
<Window x:Class="IAI.UserInterface.Views.Core.SplashScreen"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:IAI.UserInterface.Views.Core.Behaviors"
        xmlns:splash="clr-namespace:IAI.UserInterface.ViewModels.Core"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="SplashScreen"
        Height="480" Width="640"
        WindowStyle="None"
        Topmost="True"
        ShowInTaskbar="False"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        MouseDown="SplashScreen_OnMouseDown"
        behaviors:DialogCloseBehavior.DialogResult="{Binding DialogResult}"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance IsDesignTimeCreatable=False, Type=splash:SplashViewModel}">

    <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="../Resources/SplashBackground.png"/>
    </Window.Background>

    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock FontFamily="Verdana"
                       FontSize="48"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       TextAlignment="Center"
                       Opacity="0.7"
                       Text="{Binding MachineFamily}" Margin="0,0,0,16">
            </TextBlock>

            <TextBlock FontFamily="Verdana"
                       FontWeight="Light"
                       FontSize="16"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       TextAlignment="Center"
                       Opacity="0.7"
                       Text="{Binding VersionInfo, StringFormat=Version: {0}}">
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

The `OnStartup` implementation (cleaned up, to only show relevant parts for this problem)

```
    private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        // DispatcherHelper should be initialized from the UI thread for which the Static Main is appropriate
        DispatcherHelper.Initialize();
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));

        var application = Current;
        string machineNumber = "some identifier";
        try
        {
            var version = "some version";

            var splashViewModel = new SplashViewModel(versionTrimmed);
            var t = new Thread(() =>
            {
                var splash = ShowSplashScreen(splashViewModel);
                splash.ShowDialog();
            });
            t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            t.Start();

            // Removed actual startup behavior (loading config etc)...

            var mainWindow = new MainWindow { DataContext = new MainViewModel() };
            System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow = mainWindow;
            splashViewModel.DialogResult = true;

            mainWindow.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             // removed for simplicity
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I found the problem after all...

It had nothing to do with the Splashscreen at all. The problem was that the MainWindow shows the Login window in an OnWindowLoaded event. The Login Window is modal, so effectively **blocks** the `mainWindow.Show`.

We solved it by pushing the "show login window" back on the event queue. This way windows can show the dialog, set it active, and then the modal dialog will show straight after.

```
    // Next line was blocked by OnLoad event which showed the modal dialog for login window
    mainWindow.Show();
    // Next line would not execute until user manually pulled the main window to front, and logged in (which no longer was necessary then, because the user already solved the problem manually of course)
    mainWindow.Activate();
```

We now trigger the Login window to show as follows:

```
    void ShowLoginWindow() => _loginViewModel.ShowWindow();
    // Enforce that the login window is pushed on the event queue so that the windows load event 
    // is not blocked by whatever happens in the login window
    // After loading the main window, it must be activated so that windows can show it as foreground app
    DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)ShowLoginWindow);
```